# SELECT rows where numeric range specified by two fields (start - end) does not overlap with range specified in any other rows

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
id  score   start_time  end_time
1   60      25          30
2   85      5           10
3   90      10          15
4   100     0           20
```

I would like to perform the query

`SELECT * FROM table`

`WHERE the range between start_time and end_time doesn't overlap with anything in the result set ordered by score DESC`

So in this case the result set would be:

```
id  score   start_time  end_time
4   100     0           20
1   60      25          30
```

since the range between `start_time` and `end_time` for `table.id =2` and `table.id =3` overlapped with the range between `start_time` and `end_time` for `table.id =4` and the `score` of `table.id =4` was greater than the score of `table.id =2` and `table.id =3`

Is it possible to do this strictly through mysql?

Comment: u want maximum score,start and endtime??

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you're asking

Comment: I think this is possible only with a stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT: Sorry, had a minor mistake in there. Now it really works.

Set up test data:

```
create table test(
id int,
score int,
start_time int,
end_time int
);

insert into test values
(5, 95, 0, 15), /*extra test case from me*/
(1,   60,      25,          30),
(2,   85,      5,           10),
(3,   90,      10,          15),
(4,   100,     0,           20)
;
```

The function which is needed:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS checkOverlap$$
CREATE FUNCTION checkOverlap(p_id INT, p_score INT, p_stime INT, p_etime INT)
RETURNS BOOL
READS SQL DATA 
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE result INT DEFAULT TRUE;

DECLARE stime, etime INT;

DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT start_time, end_time FROM test WHERE id != p_id AND score > p_score;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

OPEN cur1;

read_loop: LOOP
FETCH cur1 INTO stime, etime;
IF done THEN
LEAVE read_loop;
END IF;

IF ((p_stime >= stime AND p_stime <= etime) OR (p_etime >= stime AND p_etime <= etime)) THEN
SET result = FALSE;
END IF;
END LOOP;

CLOSE cur1;

RETURN result;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

How to use the function:

```
select *
from
test
where
checkOverlap(id, score, start_time, end_time) = TRUE
order by score desc
```

P.S: Really nice question. Was fun to solve